# Is it possible to create a single add In to use in both 2010 and 2013 outlook?

Tags: c#, vsto

I have created an add In using VS2013 with targeted framework 4.5. Its working fine in Outlook 2013 (System spec: Windows 8.1, Visual studio 2013 and office 2013).

But when I try to use the same in Outlook 2010 I am getting an error message "The common language runtime could not be loaded by (add in path). Contact your administrator for further assistance.". I have installed required .net framework and Microsoft visual studio 2010 tools for office runtime (Testing machine with windows 7 and office 2010).

Answer (score 0):

Solutions that were created by using Visual Studio 2013 can run in Office 2013, Office 2010, or the 2007 Microsoft Office system. However, the solution can use only those features and APIs that are available in all three versions of Office. You can read more about that in the [Running Solutions in Different Versions of Microsoft Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772080.aspx) article.

Make sure that you have got the full edition of the .net framework installed, not the Client Profile.